# Is there a way to add more than one gradle dependencies with one command?

Tags: android, gradle

Suppose i have a `dependencies.gradle` which declares all dependencies for  all of my project modules:

```
def versions = [:]
versions.lifecycle = "2.2.0-alpha03"
ext.versions = versions

def deps = [:]
def lifecycle = [:]
lifecycle.runtime = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:$versions.lifecycle"
lifecycle.java8 = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$versions.lifecycle"
lifecycle.compiler = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$versions.lifecycle"
lifecycle.viewmodel_ktx = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$versions.lifecycle"
deps.lifecycle = lifecycle
ext.deps = deps
```

Now if my app module needs to use `lifecycle` library, i need to add these to `build.gradle`:

```
implementation deps.lifecycle.runtime
implementation deps.lifecycle.java8
implementation deps.lifecycle.compiler
implementation deps.lifecycle.viewmodel_ktx
```

My question is, is there a way to add `lifecycle` dependencies to app module with only one command, something like this:

```
implementation deps.lifecycle
```

I have already tried that and got this error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultExternalModuleDependency.
   > Name must not be null!
```

Comment: `implementation deps.lifecycle*` or `implementation deps.lifecycle.*` ?

Comment: It does not work: `unexpected token: *`

Comment: I doubt if there is currently a possible way to reference multiple artifacts using a single implementation statement. You would probably have to call `implementation` on each individual artifacts. Nevertheless that looks like a must have.